# C# LINQ to XML - Not Finding Elements or Descendants

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xsd, readxml

I'm having trouble using LINQ to XML to read my xml file. I have attached a portion of the xml schema.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd" id="sdnList">
  -<xs:element name="sdnList"> 
    -<xs:complexType> 
      -<xs:sequence> 
        -<xs:element name="publshInformation" maxOccurs="1"> 
         -<xs:complexType> 
          -<xs:sequence> 
             <xs:element name="Publish_Date" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/> 
            <xs:element name="Record_Count" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int"/> 
           </xs:sequence> 
          </xs:complexType> 
         </xs:element> 
       -<xs:element name="sdnEntry" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
         -<xs:complexType> 
           -<xs:sequence> 
              <xs:element name="uid" type="xs:int"/> 
              <xs:element name="firstName" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/> 
              <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/> 
              <xs:element name="title" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/> 
              <xs:element name="sdnType" type="xs:string"/> 
              <xs:element name="remarks" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/> 

              ....CONTINUES FROM HERE
```

The code I'm using is as follows.

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("c:/OFACTemp/sdn.xml");

            var sdnEntry = from item in doc.Root.Descendants("sdnEntry")
                           select new
                           {
                               uid = item.Element("uid").Value,
                               firstName = item.Element("firstName").Value
                           };

            string test = "";
            foreach (var p in sdnEntry)
                test = "Id: " + p.uid + " First Name: " + p.firstName;
```

When I break point through the code, doc loads fine and I see proper data.  Doc.Root is populated but Descendants appears to have nothing. Then once down to my foreach statement the sdnEntry yields no results. This seems so simple but I can't figure out why I can't select anything. I've also tried using Elements in place of Descendants and same result. ***End result I need to take the xml and create C# objects.***

In addition, a side question would be how would sdnEntry be handled if some sdnEntrys have for example a first name and others do not? If a first name doesn't exist for an sdnEntry then the firstName element tag doesn't even exist in the xml file.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a sample of the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
-<sdnList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  -<publshInformation> 
     <Publish_Date>05/16/2013</Publish_Date> 
     <Record_Count>5493</Record_Count>
   </publshInformation> 
   -<sdnEntry> 
     <uid>10</uid> 
     <lastName>ABASTECEDORA NAVAL Y INDUSTRIAL, S.A.</lastName> 
     <sdnType>Entity</sdnType> 
    -<programList> 
       <program>CUBA</program> 
     </programList> 
    -<akaList> 
      -<aka> 
         <uid>4</uid> 
         <type>a.k.a.</type> 
         <category>strong</category> 
         <lastName>ANAINSA</lastName> 
       </aka> 
     </akaList> 
    -<addressList> 
      -<address> 
         <uid>7</uid> 
         <country>Panama</country> 
         </address> 
     </addressList>  
   </sdnEntry>
```

Comment: Your code is looking for XML elements named `sdnEntry`, whereas your XML has elements named `element` with attributes called `name` that have values of `sdnEntry`

Comment: I have no idea why, but when i see linq to xml i get the same feeling that i get when i'm watching a bad horror movie.

Comment: Can you show a part of the XML ? That is only the XSD...

Comment: @paul, so how do I read and pull out the "uid" and "firstName"?

sexta, here is one sdnEntry from the xml. Sorry, I should have posted that before. This shown sdnEntry doesn't not have a first name whereas other sdnEntrys do.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
    -<sdnList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
      -<publshInformation> 
         <Publish_Date>05/16/2013</Publish_Date> 
         <Record_Count>5493</Record_Count> 
       </publshInformation> 
       -<sdnEntry> 
          <uid>10</uid> 
          <lastName>ABASTECEDORA NAVAL Y INDUSTRIAL, S.A.</lastName> 
          <sdnType>Entity</sdnType> 
          -<programList> 
             <program>CUBA</program> 
           </programList> 
          +<akaList>-

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get the xml to post in better format.

Comment: I posted the formatted xml in my original post.

Answer (score 4):

You need to take the default namespace into account, with LINQ to XML you do that by declaring

```
XNamespace df = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd";
```

or alternatively dynamically with

```
XNamespace df = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
```

then you need to use the `XNamespace` object to construct `XName`s in your query with e.g.

```
       var sdnEntry = from item in doc.Root.Descendants(df + "sdnEntry")
                       select new
                       {
                           uid = (string)item.Element(df + "uid"),
                           firstName = (string)item.Element(df + "firstName")
                       };
```

Answer (score 0):

removing this part from the top line worked for me. I have no idea why its like this. but it worked.
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd"

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using the XmlSerializer to solve my issue. Once the xml file was downloaded via FTP I used the following code. I was then able to use C# to populate my C# objects.

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();               
StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
string xmlString = sreader.ReadToEnd();        
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(sdnList));
TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString); 
sdnList = (sdnList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```